# How to delay a subscription until another publisher emits a specific sequence?

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

Let's say I have a `Flowable<Integer> sequence` which emits coded events. Another `Flowable<Boolean> task` needs to be delayed until `sequence` emits a certain sequence (say, `1`, `2`, `3`). How would I do that?

Currently, I have the `task` flowable delayed until a certain value is emitted, like so:

```
task = task.delaySubscription(sequence.filter(i -> i == 42));
```

I tried to accomplish this with `buffer(3)`, but it doesn't work in case the total count of emitted values was not divisible with 3:

```
task = task.delaySubscription(sequence.buffer(3).filter(vals -> vals.get(0) == 1 && vals.get(1) == 2 && vals.get(2) == 3));

// This fails
sequence.onNext(42);
sequence.onNext(1);
sequence.onNext(2);
sequence.onNext(3);
task.test().assertValueCount(1).assertValue(true);

// While this works
sequence.onNext(1);
sequence.onNext(2);
sequence.onNext(3);
task.test().assertValueCount(1).assertValue(true);
```

I'd need both of these cases to work; the only thing matters are the three most recently emitted items.

Comment: Try buffer(3, 1)

Comment: @Dmitry That won't help, it'll fail if the emitted item count mod 3 == 2.

Comment: Is task a hot Observable?

Comment: `Flowable<Integer> sequence; sequence.onNext(1);` does not compile. Provide a working prototype of the code, then probably someone would have fixed it.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov it's actually a processor upstream, but is passed as a Flowable to the code in question. The code example is basically a simplified version; just replace the Flowable with eg. a PublishProcessor.

Comment: @JohnWowUs `task` is not hot, but `sequence` is.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe by implementing a custom filter?

```
private static class SequencePredicate implements Predicate<Integer> {
    private final List<Integer> searchedSequence;
    private LinkedList<Integer> remaining;

    private SequencePredicate(final List<Integer> searchedSequence) {
        this.searchedSequence = searchedSequence;
        this.remaining = new LinkedList<>(searchedSequence);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean test(final Integer integer) throws Exception {
        boolean result = false;

        if (remaining.isEmpty()) {
            result = true;
        } else if (remaining.getFirst().equals(integer)) {
            remaining.removeFirst();
            result = remaining.isEmpty();
        } else if (remaining.size() < searchedSequence.size()) {
            remaining = new LinkedList<>(searchedSequence);
        }
        return result;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Flowable<Integer> sequence = Flowable.just(3, 5, 1, 2, 6, 1, 2, 3, 8, 9);
    // Flowable<Integer> sequence = Flowable.just(3, 5, 1, 2, 6, 1, 2, 8, 9, 10);
    List<Integer> searchedSequence = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);

    Flowable<Integer> delayFlowable = sequence.doOnNext(n -> System.out.println("before: " + n))
                                              .filter(new SequencePredicate(searchedSequence))
                                              .doOnNext(n -> System.out.println("after: " + n));

    Flowable<Boolean> task = Flowable.just(true);
    task.delaySubscription(delayFlowable)
        .subscribe(n -> System.out.println("task: " + n),
                   Throwable::printStackTrace,
                   () -> System.out.println("task: that's the end!"));

    Flowable.timer(10, SECONDS) // just for blocking the main thread
            .blockingSubscribe();
}
```